# Supremum and infimum of $\{\frac{m}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{m}: m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $$S=\left\{\frac{m}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{m}: m,n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}.$$ I think that $\sup S =\infty$ since the set is unbounded from above. By AG inequality, $\inf S =2$.

Am I right?

Any help is welcome.

Comment: Your answer is correct. But can you say why $\inf S$ is not greater than $2$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy $\frac{m}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{m}>=\frac{m}{n}+\frac{n}{m}>=2\sqrt{\frac{m}{n}\frac{n}{m}}=2$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy In my book it is said that sup S does not exist?

Comment: That does not complete the answer. Some other inequality may show that every element of the set is $>3$. You have to find elments of the set arbitrarily close to $2$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy But $lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}=0$, does this helps?So, I'll choose n,m large.

Comment: You can use the fact that $\frac {n+1} n+\frac 1 n+\frac  1 {n+1}+\frac n {n+1} \to 2$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Your answer is correct. However using the AM-GM Inequality, you have got a lower bound only. You cannot determine the $\operatorname{inf}$ using AM-GM Inequality

To determine the $\operatorname{inf}$ use the following.

When $m=n$, then $$\frac{m}{n}+\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{n}+\frac{n}{m}=2+\frac{2}{n}$$

Now use the fact that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2+\frac{2}{n}=2$$